# Time mask in TMaskEdit

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

Is it real to write mask for correct time input? 
Max hours: 23
Max mins: 59
23:59

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Funtime, why you are using a [`TMaskEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Mask.TMaskEdit) componnet? instead try a using a a [`TDateTimePicker`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker). You must set the [`format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.Format) property to `HH:mm` and the [`DateMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.DateMode) property to `dmUpDown` and will look like this.

[image]

And now you can access the current time selected reading the [`Time`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.Time) property

Comment: Not really TMaskEdit. It's DBEditEh grid.

Comment: You have to set Kind property to dtkTime as well to ensure all works fine.